# How can i loop through all Clients and return timespan which is not stay between client.time_at and client.get_done_at?

Tags: python

Here is mine function, try to return the time slot which is not in the time client had book.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    start_work_at = models.Timefield()
    end_work = models.Timefield()
    def get_clients(self):
        allClient = self.clients.all()
        return allClient
    def get_avilable(self, day):
            start = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1, hour=self.start_work_at.hour, minute=self.start_work_at.minute)
            end = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1, hour=self.end_work.hour, minute=self.end_work.minute)
            clients = self.get_clients().filter(day_comes=day)
            while start < end:
                if clients:
                    for client in clients:
                        if start.time() >= client.time_at and start.time() < client.get_done_at():
                            start += timedelta(minutes=15)
                        else:
                            yield start
                            start += timedelta(minutes=15)
                else:
                    start += timedelta(minutes=30)

class Client(models.Model):
    technician = models.ForeignKey(Technician, related_name="clients")
    time_at = models.Timefield()
    day_comes = models.DateField()
    def get_done_at():
        return time_at + timedelta(minutes=45)
```

If I have one client, it's work. but if there are two, it messed up. what I do wrong?
Sorry, first time questions.

- if Employee work from 7am-11am, with a client book at 7 and the work take 45-minute. the func will return all times span from 7:45 to 11. this works.
- but if Employee have first client at 7am and second at 8am. i expect function return all time span from 8:45 to 11. but it did not work.
- instead function return all time span from 7 to 11 if Employee have 2 or more clients
- something wrong with the For loop???

i attached pics but some how it does not show.
Thanks again for response.[image: this is how it supposed to]

[image: this is how it went wrongs]

Comment: This is difficult to answer because we don't know what you mean when you say "it messed up". What results were you expecting. What results did you get? We also don't know what 'self.get_clients()' returns, because we don't know what kind of class `self` is.

Comment: sorry! first time question! i just post again. thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with current logic includes **looping across clients** and **yielding times**. In your existing implementation, you cycle over customers for each time slot. That could result in issues because you are not accurately forwarding the start time when you find a booked session. Now, when it comes to, **Yielding Times** If a time slot does not match the current client's booking, you yield it; however, this does not take into account other clients' bookings.
I would personally take a different approach here - so here's idea:
Instead of iterating across clients for every time period, you'd make a list of all booked timeslots, and iterate across the time period, checking to see whether each slot is **not** already booked.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Employee(models.Model):
    #.......

    def get_available(self, day):
        work_start = datetime.combine(day, self.start_work_at)
        work_end = datetime.combine(day, self.end_work)
        clients = self.get_clients().filter(day_comes=day)
        booked_slots = [datetime.combine(day, client.time_at) for client in clients]

        slot = work_start
        while slot < work_end:
            if not any(slot <= booked <= slot + timedelta(minutes=45) for booked in booked_slots):
                yield slot
            slot += timedelta(minutes=15)

class Client(models.Model):
    # .....

    def get_done_at(self):
        return self.time_at + timedelta(minutes=45)
```

The code will now generate time slots that begin at `start_work_at` and terminate at `end_work` in 15-minute increments. It does checks each slot to see if any other appointments are scheduled at that time. If there is no overlap, the slot is reported as available.
The check slot `<= booked <= slot + timedelta(minutes=45)` verifies that the slot does not conflict with any scheduled appointments.

Bear in mind following:

- Time zones (if application requires it)
- You might want handling of cases where appointments can be `<` , `>` than period of 45 minutes. This is with assumption of a fixed duration - 45 minutes for each appointment.
- Also it doesn't handle partial overlapses (7:30 to 8:15 appointments won't prevent you from using the 8:00 time frame. If you want to allow it, you will have to edit the logic

Comment: thanks for well explained. you're wonderful. good days